# how to draw perfect line in webgl

Tags: html5-canvas, webgl, webgl2, twgl.js

I want to draw perfect line using webgl. I had not set anything in renderer context. What should I enable or set or give what option to `canvas.getContext` to help me draw a line which seems good? I think use linear and somethings (I have no idea) to give me a line which is not like stairs.

```js
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2',{
        antialias: true,
        depth: false,
        stencil: false
    });
    gl.viewport(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);



array = {
  pos: {
    numComponents: 2,
    data: [-0.03, -1  ,  0.03, 1],
  },
};

Program = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [
  `#version 300 es
    precision highp float;
    in vec2 pos;
    void main(){gl_Position = vec4(pos, 0.0 , 1.0);}`,
  `#version 300 es
    precision highp float;
    out vec4 Color;
    void main(){Color.xyz = vec3(0.0) ; Color.a = 1.0;}
    `
]);
Attrib = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, array);

obj = {
  type: gl.LINES,
  programInfo: Program,
  bufferInfo: Attrib,
  //count: 1
};
requestAnimationFrame(() => twgl.drawObjectList(gl, [obj]));
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi unfortunately your question does not seem to be very detailed. In order to get some help you should provide some of your code.  Show us what you have tried so far. Also please consider reading the [Asking guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the [Helpcenter](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: I see no *stars*. Whether or not the canvas is antialiased is up to the browser. You can request it to NOT antialias and it won't but asking it to antialias the browser is allowed to ignore your request. You can make the size of your canvas larger than you display it. You can also create your own antialiased framebuffer and resolve that to the canvas. But, you should know that WebGL2 only supports lines 1 pixel wide. For anything else you need to [draw lines yourself using triangles](https://mattdesl.svbtle.com/drawing-lines-is-hard).

Answer (score 0):

I guess by `not like stairs` you mean aliasing. According to the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/getContextAttributes) you can turn on the according flag when retrieving the webgl rendering context.

Assuming you have a canvas like this:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

You can turn on antialiasing by:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl',
                 { antialias: true });
```

For further information please read the according [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/getContextAttributes).

Comment: I had did that but nothing changed. it is still bad

Comment: @MohamadHoseinAlahdadian Please provide some code in your question. Otherwise it is hard to identify the exact problem.

Comment: That looks to be about as good as you can get when I zoomed in.  The quality of the line being determined by the resolution of the display also.

Comment: I think WebGL limits the MSAA to the vital minimum of 2x or 4x (this appear more to be 2x). And the answere is YES it is possible to improves this using GLSL or combined CPU code + GLSL, by various methods, with various result. But except if you choose a cheap FSAA-like technic (which would probably don't resolve the issue) this will take to you a whole new set of development (like reimplementing MSAA manually with more than 2 samples).

Comment: Also, you have to keep in mind that WebGL (or OpenGL) is not dedicated to draw simples 2D geometry in black on white (to acheive this, you'd better using the simple Context2D)... So the priority is not on AA, because this : https://resources-premium.vzaar.com/vzaar/vz2/cb1/target/vz2cb130945f594bc58912b636a8019ab9.jpg is more what you are supposed to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the better resolution (**width** and **height** attributes) than the real size in CSS **styles** attribute. For example:

*Original size:*

[image]

*Size 2x + styles:*

```
<canvas width=800 height=400 styles="width: 400; height: 200;" id="canvas"/>
```

[image]

Both screenshots made from the real screen and not scaled.